Find all value of $a$ such that the problem has a global solution

Consider the function $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by
$f(x, y) = ax + 8y$, where $a$ is a real parameter, and the set $C =
 \{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid 2x + y \geq 5, \, 3x - y \geq 1\}$.
Find all values of $a$ such that the problem $\min_{(x, y) \in C} f(x,
> y)$ has a global solution.

My attempt:
Since $$ax + 8y = \frac{a + 24}{5}(2x + y) + \frac{a - 16}{5}(3x - y)$$
If $a\geq 16$ then $\min_{(x, y) \in C} f(x,y)$ has a global solution.
I don't know are there any values of $a$ s.t $a<16$ satisfying the problem?
Could anyone help me?

What is the meaning  of $f(x, > y)$, please?

The function decreases in the direction $(-a, -8)$ (the opposite of its gradient). If $(-a,-8)$ points in directions where $C$ is bounded, a minimum exists. If $(-a,-8)$ point in directions where $C$ is unbounded, no minimum exists, as for any point in $C$, by moving further in this direction, you can find a point where $f$ is lower. (Since $f$ is linear, we don't have to worry about "global" - any minimum will be a global minimum.)
$C$ is unbounded in directions from $(1, -2)$ counterclockwise to $(1,3)$, or slopes from $-2$ to $3$. The slope of lines in the direction $(-a,-8)$ is $\frac 8a$, so $-2 < \frac 8a < 3$. If $a < 0$, then $-2a > 8 > 3a$, giving $a < -4$ and $a < \frac 83$. That is, $a < -4$. If $a > 0$, then $-2a < 8 < 3a$, giving $a > -4$ and $a > \frac 83$. That is, $a > \frac 83$.
So the problem has a solution (necessarily global) when $a < -4$ or $a > \frac 83$.
